# SQL Query to check if today is Employee's birthday

Tags: sql, datetime, datediff

Can any one tell me how to get the list of an employee who have their birthdays today ....

Thanks,
Vishal

Comment: @DanAndrews, not unconditionally :)

Comment: See my solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/69647961/7886965

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Employees
WHERE DATEPART(d, DateOfBirth) = DATEPART(d, GETDATE())
    AND DATEPART(m, DateOfBirth) = DATEPART(m, GETDATE())
```

Comment: One comment to make on this is that this assumes that `DateOfBirth` is is stored in the same time zone as that set on the SQL server. Should the `DateOfBirth` be stored in UTC then `GETUTCDATE()` would be required.

Comment: @Dems I checked the execution plan in my sample database and it at least claims to be using the index.

Comment: @miikaL. - It will be using a scan at best.  It's still a full scan and not a seek.

Comment: But its a scan on the index, and not a full table scan, no?

Comment: @MiikaL. - Yes, it may scan the index, but it's still a full scan.  The alternative in my answer is really long winded, but yields a seek instead of a scan.

Comment: This solution is incomplete as it doesn't handle Leap years, see my solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/69647961/7886965

Answer (score 1):

Ideally a bit more information on the structure of your data sources would help, but a simple answer providing your employee records have a D.O.B. field would be to compare the day and month of this against the current system date in the where clause of your query.

Something along the following lines:

```
select * from wherever
where
....
(
  datepart(d, EmployeeDOB) = datepart(d, getdate()) and
  datepart(m, EmployeeDOB) = datepart(m, getdate())
)
.....
```

Comment: Hey andy , thnx a lot....
I got it working..
:)

Comment: @VishalAvhad - Please note, this option obfuscates the INDEX and will force a full table scan.  If you have a large number of records this will be a significant overhead.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` month and day of employee's birthday match today's month and day (obviously). More specific instructions would require more input.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
select e.name from employeeTable e
where right(e.birthday) = right(convert(varchar(8), getdate(), 112), 4)
```

or

```
select e.name from employeeTable e
where datepart(d, e.birthday) = datepart(d, getdate())
    and datepart(m, e.birthday) = datepart(m, getdate())
```

Comment: afaik this will also obfuscate and index on the `birthday` field.

Comment: @Dems I keep forgetting that :)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is much more long winded, it does avoid having to scan the entire table looking for matches.

```
WITH
  a_century AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS year
  UNION ALL
  SELECT year * 2 + 0 AS year FROM a_century WHERE year < 64
  UNION ALL
  SELECT year * 2 + 1 AS year FROM a_century WHERE year < 64
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
  a_century
    ON yourTable.birthday = DATEADD(year, -a_century.year, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getDate()), 0))
```