# Birthday reminder in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to select those people whose date of birth matches with current system date.

My SQL query is:

```
select testtable.task 
from testtable 
where testtable.dates like (select SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 10), 1, 5))
```

I have written this in SQL Server.

The issue is it is not returning any data but the inner subquery is working perfectly fine.

Please specify the solutions for both the cases when date is stored as a string and when date is stored as date type.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Re: _"when date is stored as a string"_: In which specific format? There are many possibilities, e.g. MM/DD/YY, D.MMM.YYYY, YYYY-MM-DD etc. Note: Do *not* store dates as strings if you can store them in an actual date/time datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `testtable.dates` is of type `Date` `DateTime` or `DateTime2`, you can simply use this query:

```
select testtable.task 
from testtable 
where month(testtable.dates) = month(getdate())
and day(testtable.dates) = day(getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Accepted solution doesn't take into account Leap years, so if someone birthday is on the 2020-02-29 he will only get a notification every 4 years.

This query returns on non leap years the 02/29 birthdays on the 02/28 like most countries and social medias.

MariaDB/MySQL:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    Employees
WHERE
CASE
    WHEN MONTH(CURDATE()) = 2 AND DAY(CURDATE()) = 28
        AND DAY(ADDDATE(CURDATE(), 1)) != 29
    THEN MONTH(Employees.DateOfBirth) = 2 AND 
        DAY(Employees.DateOfBirth) IN (28, 29)
    ELSE MONTH(Employees.DateOfBirth) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND 
        DAY(Employees.DateOfBirth) = DAY(CURDATE())
END
```

MsSQL:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM 
    Employees
WHERE
    (MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 AND DAY(GETDATE()) = 28 AND DAY(DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())) != 29) AND
    (MONTH(Employees.DateOfBirth) = 2 AND DAY(Employees.DateOfBirth) IN (28, 29))
    OR
    NOT (MONTH(GETDATE()) = 2 AND DAY(GETDATE()) = 28 AND DAY(DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())) != 29) AND
    (MONTH(Employees.DateOfBirth) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(Employees.DateOfBirth) = DAY(GETDATE()))
```

Comment: My answer does exactly what the OP asked for: "I want to select those people whose date of birth matches with current system date." It might not be the best option when it comes to people that was born on February 29th, but it works perfectly well for the question's description and for 1459 days in any 4 years (which is 1460 days).

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes the answer is technically correct for body question. I posted this as OP subject is "Birthday reminder in SQL Server" and the usual use case is that you want everyone to get a reminder every year, and this page comes up on google search and can lead other people to miss this detail.